# Closure of shopping related questions best option?

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I just saw the following post on superuser:
[superuser.com posting 138651](https://superuser.com/questions/138651/where-do-i-buy-a-router-that-can-be-customized-closed)

The post was closed but it seems like it would have been better to edit the question to what I think the poster was really asking which in my opinion is :
Is there a router I can modify to run my c program on?

I suppose I will have to work my way to get enough reputation to make this edit myself and possibly reopen the posting.

Maybe a suggestion for meta stack overflow is to allow the posting of suggestion on how to improve postings after they are closed?

Comment: "allow the posting of suggestion on how to improve postings after they are closed"?  that's what comments are for.  you can still leave comments on closed questions (assuming you have the rep to leave comments in the first place).  *locked* questions, on the other hand, can't be commented upon.

Comment: Since you have 200 rep on SO, clear your account associations, then reconnect them and you'll have the rep to comment on SU.

Comment: I see, I just got my rep up so I can comment. But the user who closed it was not as helpful as I though he could have been I think is more accurately my problem with it.

Comment: I would upvote your comment @random if I could atm :D

Comment: @Randy: SU is the wild west; there are lots of times when i'd like to leave more detailed comments than i have time for.

Comment: What are you actually asking for? Lower the rep to comment? Lower the rep to edit? Have a place to place comments? A problem with the moderator's terseness in closing that SU question? Or to have shopping questions stay open despite being too localised?

Comment: If it were up to me, I would say any closure would require the closer to make a positive suggestion to help the poster turn a bad question into a good one. Currently it seems the closer simply has to specify a preset reason why it was closed. 
I think I phrased this request the way I did because I am trying to work within the system as it is, not sure how friendly the responses would be if I asked for major changes.

But I also don't see why shopping questions are that harmful either, answers would be subjective, but most answers on these sites are anyway?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36056/not-the-shopping

Comment: @Randy - "most answers on these sites are subjective anyway". I don't think so. Subjective questions and answers are highly discouraged.

Comment: I agree with @Gnoupi -- subjective questions get downvoted/closed pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the closure was correct. Editing the question in the way you said would be a pretty big edit -- I think the appropriate course of action is for the question to be closed with a clear description of why ([Shopping and/or hardware recommendation questions not allowed on SuperUser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36056/not-the-shopping)) and if the question's author is interested in asking his question again but this time asking "*Is* there a router I can modify to run my c program on?", then s/he can do so. But as a new question.